# Perl (Net::SSH::Perl) script sometimes hangs while running remote command but shell script works

Tags: perl, jenkins

I have written a Perl script which copies a deliverable on machine A (and also takes a backup of the same resource on another machine B) and then invokes a shell script which is already present on machine A. This shell script deploys the deliverable (generally a war file) on machine A. Though this whole task of copying and invoking the shell script could have been written in bash quiet easily, I thought of using Perl just because I had not written a Perl program for quite some time. We have a master-slave setup of Jenkins and the Perl script runs from the Jenkins slave.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use File::Copy;
use Getopt::Long;
use File::Basename;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SCP::Expect;

my ($conf_file, $environment, $action, $job, $dest_file, $user, $host, $IP, $TARGET_SERVER, $JOB_ENV, $JENKINS_JOB, $wrapper, $src_file, $src_path, $src_dist_path, $src_dist_full_path, $dist_temp_archive_path, $dist_archive_host, $archive_user, $scpe, $id_file, @id_file, @array, $line);

my $ITE = "server.ite.com";

if ($environment eq "release") {
    $IP = $ITE;
    $JOB_ENV = "Release_";
    $JENKINS_JOB = substr $ENV{'JOB_NAME'}, 8;
    $dist_temp_archive_path = "/home/ec2-user/release_archive";
}

$conf_file = "/home/ec2-user/SCM/generic/deploy_build.cnf";
open (FH, "<", $conf_file) or die "Cannot open < $conf_file: $!";

while (<FH>) {
    if ( $_ =~ /\b$JENKINS_JOB\b/ ) {
        push @array, $_;
    } else {
        next;
    }
}

foreach $line (@array) {
    ($job, $src_dist_path, $dest_file, $user, $wrapper) = split(':', $line);

    if ($dest_file eq "") {
        ($src_file, $src_path) = fileparse($src_dist_path);
        $dest_file = $src_file;
    }

    $job = $JOB_ENV . $job;

    $id_file = "/home/ec2-user/.ssh/sandy";
    @id_file = ("/home/ec2-user/.ssh/sandy");

    if ($action eq "copy_distributable") {
        printf "Initiating subroutine to copy distributable on remote machine...\n";
        &copy_distributable;
    } elsif ($action eq "exec_wrapper") {
        if (defined $wrapper && length $wrapper) {
            printf "Initiating subroutine for executing wrapper on remote machine...\n";
            &exec_wrapper;
        } else {
            printf "*** No wrapper specified ****\n";
        }
    }
}

sub copy_distributable {
    $archive_user="ec2-user";
    $src_dist_full_path = "$ENV{WORKSPACE}/$src_dist_path";
    $dist_archive_host = "55.666.77.88";

    if ( -f $src_dist_full_path ) {
        $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(identity_file => $id_file, host => $dist_archive_host);
        $scpe->scp("$src_dist_full_path", "$dist_temp_archive_path/$dest_file");

        $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(identity_file => $id_file, host => $IP, user => $user);
        $scpe->scp("$src_dist_full_path", "/home/$user/$dest_file");

        printf "Deliverable copied on deployment machine. Now moving on to next task of archiving the deliverable...\n\n";

        my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($dist_archive_host, "identity_files" => \@id_file);
        $ssh->login($archive_user);
        printf "mv $dist_temp_archive_path/$dest_file $dist_temp_archive_path/latest\n\n";
        my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("mv $dist_temp_archive_path/$dest_file $dist_temp_archive_path/latest");
        printf "Output: $stdout\n" if $stdout;
        printf "Error: $stderr\n" if $stderr;
        printf "Deliverable archived on Jenkins master\n";
    } else {
        printf "Deliverable not found\n";
        exit 1;
    }
}


sub exec_wrapper {
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($IP, "identity_files" => \@id_file);
    $ssh->login($user);
    my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("~/release/$wrapper");
    printf "Output: $stdout\n" if $stdout;
    printf "Error: $stderr\n" if $stderr;
}
```

Details of Jenkins slave box where the build workspace is:

```
[ec2-user@jenkins_slave2 ~]$ uname -a
Linux jenkins_slave 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 2 09:36:59 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[ec2-user@jenkins_slave2 ~]$ free -m
              total      used       free       shared   buffers         cached
Mem:          7228       5688       1539          0         72           3824
-/+ buffers/cache:     1791       5436
Swap:        16382       163       16219
```

Also, there is sufficient memory on the box where the deliverable is copied and finally deployed. Disk space is also not an issue on either of the machines. Both are Linux instances running on AWS.

Now the issue is that though the program usually runs fine, many a times, it hangs when the deployment script (shell script) is called. To debug, I ran the Perl script in Jenkins using Devel::Trace. When the build got stuck, I aborted the build. As soon as I aborted the build, I got a heap space error so I added Xms & Xmx parameters to set initial and maximum Java heap size respectively. After confirming that the settings are applied, I ran the builds again. A few builds passed and a few again got stuck. I don’t think increasing heap size further makes any sense. A shell script was written to do the same task and it does not require any such extra memory to run. Now I am not sure where to look for clues.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. A client uploading files via sftp would hang after 3 files. After a while I realized that the client was creating a new connection for uploading one file.

Perhaps you could open the connections (create $ssh/$scpe variables) before the foreach loop and pass the them to your copy_distributable function for reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Cornel! I started using Net::OpenSSH instead of Net::SSH::Perl and that seems to have helped. However, your advice is also worth nothing. I modified my script to incorporate your suggestion. :)

Comment: And apologies for the delay in reply. I would have replied earlier but i first wanted to modify my script and then respond. :)